# how to check if a string is valid json in c using jq

Tags: c, json, jq

basically I want to have a function `bool json_is_valid(char* input)` in c. As I use `jq` for the rest of my json stuff, I want to use it for this as well, however I am unable to find a proper way of doing it. Among other things I've tried the following:

```c
bool json_is_valid(char* input){
        jq_state* state = jq_init();
        jv compiled = jq_compile_args(state, ".", NULL);

        return !(jv_is_valid(compiled));
}
```

However, this still doesn't work. How could this be fixed?

Comment: I am not familiar with jq, but if you don't feed `input` into any of the `jq_*` function, what result do you expect? How do you parse a string and extract fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `jv_parse` can be used to validate strings of JSON.

Its declared in [*src/jv.h*](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/blob/master/src/jv.h) as:

```
jv jv_parse(const char* string);
```

Passing the result of this function to `jv_is_valid` appears to get the job done. `jv_is_valid` is defined in *src/jv.h* as:

```
static int jv_is_valid(jv x) {
    return jv_get_kind(x) != JV_KIND_INVALID;
}
```

A cursory example:

```
#include <jq.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int json_is_valid(const char *json)
{
    jv ele = jv_parse(json);
    int valid = jv_is_valid(ele);
    jv_free(ele);

    return valid;
}

int main(void)
{
    while (1) {
        char buf[512];

        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
            break;

        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';

        printf("<<%s>> Valid? %s.\n", buf, json_is_valid(buf) ? "Yes" : "No");
    }
}
```

```
{}
<<{}>> Valid? Yes.
[]
<<[]>> Valid? Yes.
[{}]
<<[{}]>> Valid? Yes.
[][]
<<[][]>> Valid? No.
"foo"
<<"foo">> Valid? Yes.
"foo":"bar"
<<"foo":"bar">> Valid? No.
51
<<51>> Valid? Yes.
{42: []}
<<{42: []}>> Valid? No.
{"42":[1, 2, 3]}
<<{"42":[1, 2, 3]}>> Valid? Yes.
'qux'
<<'qux'>> Valid? No.
```

The problem with `jq_compile` (`jq_compile_args`) is that it would seem to parse the *jq* filtering language described in [the manual](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters).

There might be a more correct method, but the [lack of a proper C API documentation](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/wiki/C-API:-libjq) makes this an unwieldy problem to research.

Comment: and if I want to return it as a bool I simply need to convert the int valid to a bool upon return right? Or are there some edge cases where it's not either 1 or 0?

Comment: I've added the definition of `jv_is_valid` to the answer for clarity. It always returns `0` or `1`, so you can safely use `bool` (`bool json_is_valid(...`, `bool valid = ...`) if you prefer.